# NullPointerException when trying to get image orientation

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, android-cursor

Hey i can't seem to understand this error.
I'm trying to select an image by taking a picture or selecting from gallery.
When i try the method on a selected image it works fine but when i take an image from camera i get the error on the `cursor.close()` line

I have this code to capture image from gallery :

```
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
    Uri selectedImage = mImageUri;
    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chosenImage2);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    try {
         bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
         .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
         //flip image if needed
         bitmap = Helpers.flipBitmap(bitmap, Helpers.getOrientation(this, selectedImage));

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Camera", e.toString());

    }

}
```

and this is the getOrientation code :

```
  public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
                null, null, null);

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getInt(0);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

This producing null pointer exception and i can't understand why.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

This is how i call the Intent :

```
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chosenImage2);
     if(imageView.getDrawable() == null){
         Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg");
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
         Uri.fromFile(photo));
         mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
         startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentResolver.query(...) may return null as you can find in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29).

Very likely `cursor.moveToFirst()` throws an `NullPointerException` stopping execution of the `try` block but running the `finally` code:
`cursor.close()` which is `null.close()` => KABAM.

You could check for `cursor != null` at various places. E.g. before entering the `try` block or in the `finally` block.

However safest way to get across this would be catching the NullPointerException.

```
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
            null, null, null);
    //cursor might be null!

    try {
        int returnMe;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            returnMe = cursor.getInt(0);
        } else {
            returnMe = -1;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return returnMe;
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        //log: no cursor found returnung -1!
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to that, it is likely to be null because your URI argument is invalid.. A probable cause would be you don't restore your activity state and the mImageUri field becomes null after turning the camera.

Comment: This makes the error go away but it dosen't get the image orientation any more. and Paul-Jan, i fail to understand how turning the camera is related, i handel the activity result and made the activity portrait only so that can't be the cause.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply by the way :) After having a proper error handling it's about time to question why the error occurs - read: Why is `cursor` null? Aus Paul-Jan pointed out chances are high `photoUri` is invalid and therefore `cursor`'s creation fails. Looking at the first code block I see the moethod is called like this `Helpers.getOrientation(this, selectedImage)` while essentially `selectedImage = mImageUri`. The latter one "descends from the code heaven". Should you not be able to fix it from here I'd suggest to open another, more specific, question for that.